StringVar doesn't update the text on a button in Python's TKinter
StringVar doesn't update the text on a button in Python's TKinter. As a matter of fct, no text is being shown. Why? I'm using Spyder 5.5.5.
Here's the code:
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk


class Main_Window(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        
        Child_Frame(self).grid(row=0, column=0)
        

class Child_Frame(ttk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        
        self.button_var = tk.StringVar(value="Connect")
        button = ttk.Button(self, textvariable=self.button_var, 
                            command = self.upd)
        button.grid(row = 0, column = 0, sticky='news')
        
    def upd(self):
        self.button_var.set('Disconnect')


Main_Window().mainloop()

Here's what I see:


What are you seeing when you run this? Because I get a Button that says "Connect" and that button changes to "Disconnect" (and stays that way) when I click it.

I did run it, I see an empty button

What environment are you running this in?  The only reason I can think of for it to fail like that is that you've somehow run the code multiple times in a single Python interpreter session, and have therefore created multiple instances of Tk().  The StringVar was created in the original instance (since you did not specify otherwise), and therefore isn't accessible by the Button (which exists in the most recent instance).

Envronment? I'm using normal Python interpreter from the official Python website, not Anaconda or something.
I also tested it in IDLE, it works there. Doesn't in Spyder.

@jasonharper if you're right, could it be a matter of setting the master param on the StringVar to the root window like so: self.button_var = tk.StringVar(self.winfo_toplevel(), value="Connect")

@JRiggles It worked, thank you
